# functional test to confirm custom route with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, functional-testing

I have a custom route for devise:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/login'   => "devise/sessions#new",       :as => :new_user_session
  get '/logout'  => 'devise/sessions#destroy',
  ...
```

I want to make sure that when the request `/login` is called, that it gets correctly routed to devise and that the response is successful.

How do you test for custom routing and a successful request?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built-in TestUnit to test, check out the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) on testing controllers.

If you're using Rspec, check out the [Rspec Github Page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) for information on testing controllers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you testing suite, personally I use [RSpec](http://rspec.info) + [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.md) for my Rails projects.
If you don't have a testing suite yet I highly recommend this guide.
http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance, I'd say you want two tests. One for the routing and one for a successful request. Using rspec, this will look something like:

```
#spec/routing/devise_routing_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Devise Routes" do
   it "should route the login correctly" do
        {:get => "login"}.should route_to(controller: "devise/sessions", action: "new")
   end
end
```

and

```
#spec/controllers/devise/session_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe Devise::Sessions do
  it "should be successful with a login request" do
    get "new"
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```